# Router with Tablet Hotspot

Tags: router, hotspot

If I have a wired router setup and my line is down, is it possible to setup a hotspot on my tablet and connect it to router via a USB cable which would allow the PCs on the network to then have internet access? without need for further configuration of the router (ie. logining into router and setuping up there)

Or would I have to go the route of a router with mobile 4G fallback which would require a sim to be directly inserted into router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often have the same problem and solve it like this:

- Buy a cheap WLAN AP that can do client mode and has a DHCP server in it
- Configure it to connect to the WLAN created by your tablet's hotspot
- When your line goes down, unplug it from the router and plug the AP in instead.

Now the way of the signal is 3G->Tablet->AP->Router, which is not perfect but as good as it gets without any reconfiguration or 2nd SIM card.